# lists become empty after modifying a ngModel

Tags: jquery, angularjs, drag-and-drop

drag and drop between 2 lists, I could have used angular-dragdrop, unfortunately it does not work in IE8, so we have to use the jquery one.

the drag and drop works fine until user enters something in a input box (which has a ngModel), then the lists become empty.

I put a watch for the input box, the lists has the items in them but they are not displaying.

here is the plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/WQSXtyj3sJ0n14IXv7YN?p=preview

edit:
I got it to work by simply adding var row = {logon: item.innerText}; and push that into obj1 obj2 array.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you're working with DOM, you should be working in a directive. I'm not sure what all the code inside your receiver function is supposed to do, but it ends up causing Angular to lose its reference to your data. It looks like your taking the DOM's innerText and turning it into an array and overwriting the model with it. Your model is an array of objects but you transform it to an array of text?

The reason you're seeing it go away when you change the model is that you never trigger a `$digest` before then. Then the $digest happens, your `ng-repeats` run and there's no longer any proper data so they return nothing. Additionally, assigning ng-model to list elements doesn't do anything. There's no functionality there.

I think you should learn about creating directives before you go any further. To solve your current problem, you can use an existing drag-drop directive found here: http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/ You said it doesn't work with IE8, but there's no reason it shouldn't work with IE8 as long as you follow the IE8 precautions outlined in the AngularJS docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie.

Comment: here is the question about drag and drop not working with IE8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731415/angular-dragdrop-not-working-with-ie

Comment: Jonathan, your assessment is wrong: "...it ends up causing Angular to lose its reference to your data...". I got it to work by simply adding var row = {logon: item.innerText}; and push that into obj1 obj2 array. It was just missing the key value. Thanks for the negative vote before you understand the person's question.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted you. I answered your question correctly, you were turning the obj from an obj to an array, which causes Angular to lose its hash value, i.e. the reference. Your transforming the model into DOM and back into a model. The way you're doing it is still incorrect and you should still be creating a directive and managing the data.